# Using egrep in Bash

Tags: bash, grep

In the following code, I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why:

```
[name@unix ~]$cat test123
123
456
789
1011
1213
[name@unix ~]$egrep ^[0-9]{1,3}$ test123
egrep: ^[0-9]3$: No such file or directory
[name@unix ~]$egrep ^[0-9]{3}$ test123
123
456
789
[name@unix ~]$
```

When I do $man egrep, I'm shown this:

{n}    The preceding item is matched exactly n times.
{n,}   The preceding item is matched n or more times.
{n,m} The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is interpreting `{1,3}` as a *brace expansion*, resulting in `grep` seeing

```
grep ^[0-9]1$ ^[0-9]3$ test123
```

as a result of which it takes `^[0-9]3$` to be an additional filename argument. You should always quote your regex to prevent such expansion by the shell i.e.

```
egrep '^[0-9]{1,3}$' test123
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense but seems non-intuitive for some reason.